# Is my attempt at proving this corollary of the LDCT correct?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$\mathbf{LDC\ Theorem:}$ Suppose that $(f_{n})$ is a sequence of integrable functions, $f_{n}: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}, $ on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ that converges pointwise to a limiting function $f:X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}}.$ If there is an integrable function $g:X \rightarrow  [0,\infty]$ such that $$|f_{n}(x)\leq g(x)| \qquad \text{ for all } x\in X \text{ and } n\in \mathbb{N}.$$ then $f$ is integrable and 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_{n} d\mu = \int f\ d\mu.$$

---

$\mathbf{Corollary:}$ 
Let the mapping $x \rightarrow f(x,\tau)$ be a measurable function on $X$ for each $\tau \in [a,b],$ and suppose that for some $t \in [a,b]$
$$f(x,t)=\lim_{\tau \rightarrow t} f(x,\tau) \text{ for each } x \in X.$$
If there exists a function $g\in L^{1}(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ such that ${f(x,\tau)} \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in X\ \tau \in [a,b]$, prove that $$\int f(x,t)\ d\mu(x)=\lim_{\tau \rightarrow t} \int f(x,\tau)\ d\mu(x).$$

---

$\textbf{Attempt}:$ 
(Heavily Edited)

Let $F(x):=  f(x,\tau)$ be a measurable function on $X$, for $t\in [a,b]$ $f(x,t)=\lim\limits_{\tau \rightarrow t} f(x,\tau)$ and $g\in L^{1}(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ such that $|{f(x,\tau)}| \leq g(x)$ for each $x \in X$. Since $f(x,t)=\lim\limits_{\tau \rightarrow t}\ f(x,\tau)$ by SFCL(as hinted by Calvin) for any $(\tau_{n}) \subset [a,b]$ such that $(\tau_{n}) \rightarrow t$ then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $f(\tau_{n})=f(t).$ Since we have a sequence of integrable functions $F_{n}(x):=f(x,\tau_{n}) \rightarrow f(x,t)$ that converge pointwise and $|{f(x,\tau)}| \leq g(x)$ by LDCT for all ${\tau_{n}\rightarrow} \subset [a,b]$ such that $\tau_{n} \rightarrow t$ then: 
 $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f(x, \tau_{n}) d\mu = \int f (x, \tau)\ d\mu \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{\tau \rightarrow t} \int f(x,\tau)\ d\mu(x) =
 \int f(x,t)\ d\mu(x). \Box $$

Comment: I'm not sure what your sequence $\tau$ is, because I don't know what $\chi_\lambda$ is. The result should follow from the sequential formulation of a continuous limit; i.e. $\lim_{x\to c} F(x) = L$ iff for any $x_n \to c$, $F(x_n) \to L$.

Comment: $\tau \in [a,b]$  where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Thank you, I will add this that to my proof. Appreciate it!

Comment: Well you wrote $f_n = f(x,\tau)$, but I can't see where the $n$ is on the right hand side. e.g. what is $\tau$ with $n=1$?

Comment: Oh, do you literally mean that $\tau$ is an "enumeration" of $[a,b]$? its not possible to do this with a sequence (=countable set of points), so if this is what you mean then its not correct

Comment: $\tau$ is an element of an interval $[a,b]$, I think my $f_{n}$ should be replaced by $f_{\tau}$. since $\chi_[a,b]$ is the characteristic function or the indicator function.

Comment: OK, but you've not defined a sequence then. You cannot apply the LDCT with this $\tau$ since it isn't a sequence, and LDCT is a result about sequences. I don't know about you, but I would define a sequence $a_n=a(n)$ of elements of $X$ to be a map $a:\mathbb N \to X$. Your $\tau$ clearly doesn't fit this

Comment: I get a sequence if I define $\chi$ right? $\chi_[a,b]=\begin{cases} 
      \tau \quad  if\ x \in A_{n} \\
      0 \quad otherwise \\
   \end{cases},
$

Comment: To define $\tau$, you introduced $\chi_\lambda$ for each $\lambda \in [a,b]$. Then to define $\chi_\lambda$, you introduced $A_n$... Your definitions are in a complicated tangle, maybe try writing it up from the start again

Comment: If you can't tell me what $\tau(1),\tau(2),\tau(3)$ are, I would very much doubt you have a sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of comments before it gets too long- You need to remember:

> **Definition.** A sequence of elements in $X$ is a map $a:\mathbb N \to X$, usually written for $n\in\mathbb N$ as $a_n$ instead of $a(n)$.

And

> **Claim.** The set $[a,b]$ is not the set of values of any one sequence $a_n$ of elements of $\mathbb R$.

**Proof.** The set $\{ a_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ is countable, while $[a,b]$ is uncountable.

To prove the main result in the question, I strongly suggest you remind yourself of the following

> **Claim. (Sequential formulation of continuous limit)** For a function $f:[a,b]\to Y$, the continuous limit $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L\in Y$ holds iff for any sequence $(x_n)\subset [a,b]$ with the sequence limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = c$, we have the sequence limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = L$.

Note carefully that sequence limits and continuous limits have [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) definitions.

Comment: @Flinsword also no, you need the result to hold for $\color{red}{all}$ sequences tending to $\color{red}{ \Huge t}$, not $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you, this should be all the help I need. I will ponder deeply about this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Flinsword glad it helps, hope it works out

Comment: Hows this logic, feels much better now. Because $f(x,t)=\lim_{\tau \rightarrow t} f(x,\tau)$ by SFCL there exists a sequence $\tau_{n}= \rightarrow \tau$ such the sequence of functions $f(x,\tau) \rightarrow f(x,t)$. Thus by LBDC ...

Comment: @Flinsword No, (1) the SFCL does not create any sequences, and (2) when you go on to say "such that ...", the sequence $\tau_n$ has disappeared, and we only see $f(x,\tau)$? Carefully write down the assumptions and what you want to prove: $\lim_{\tau \to t} F(\tau) = L$. Use the SFCL here to make what you want to prove into a statement about sequences. This is when you can apply the LDCT. (also, if you're writing this down for someone to mark by hand, I would refrain from all the abbreviations)

Comment: Yes I actually use footnotes to state the theorem/corollary\etcs. I edited the proof, It looks good to me now. I would appreciate any more comments.

Comment: @Flinsword your most recent proof is correct, good job! Some comments; `\mapsto` lets you type $x\mapsto f(x,\tau)$; I would write $(\tau_n) \to t$, not $(\tau_n) \to (t)$; After this you write $f(\tau_n) \to f(t)$, but this is a little inconsistent with the previous notation $f(x,\tau)$; I would write $F_n(x) := f(x,\tau_n)$ and $F(x) := f(x,t)$ to match the notation of LDCT as much as possible;  for functions, there are many definitions of convergence, so make sure you say that $f_n\to f$ pointwise (and not  in e.g. supremum norm), and finally, (1/2)

Comment: At the end, its really the equivalence $$\forall \tau_n\subset [a,b] : \tau_n \to t,\ \int f(x,\tau_n) dx \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int f(x,t) dx \iff \int f(x,\tau) dx \xrightarrow[\tau \to t]{} \int f(x,t) dx  $$ that you are using. (2/2) @Flinsword